# "Hide" text box from automatic Win10 keyboard showing

Tags: wpf, windows-10, on-screen-keyboard

My goal is to show Windows 10 on-screen keyboard when user clicks on text box.

Windows 10 has option to show its on-screen keyboard automatically, even outside of Tablet mode, if specific option is enabled in settings.

However, it seems this logic has some serious issues when working with WPF applications - flickering, not showing up at all etc. You can easily test it on simple WPF application with several text boxes, if you have touch screen Win10 device.

So, I've decided to control keyboard myself, which now works perfectly, with automatic keyboard display option disabled. However, I can't ensure that every users Windows 10 will have this option disabled, so I'd like to make Windows "ignore" clicks on text boxes in my WPF application, so only application itself controls keyboard visibility.

So, my question is - is there any way to make Windows ignore focus on particular text boxes?

PS. If there is no clear way to do this, I would be grateful for any hints towards how Windows actually gets information about WPF text box being edited, so I can maybe play around with my own TextBox implementations, which will not trigger this logic.

**Update:**

It seems, it is possible to remove "hooks" keyboard is using to find out that text box is focused, by using `FrameworkElementAutomationPeer` instead of `TextBoxAutomationPeer` in custom implementation of `TextBox`, yet this ruins possibility to use this text box in automation (which I don't like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a touch screen device to test on - but from my quick mouse clicking tests I seen there is a TextBox.Focusable = false;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable(v=vs.110).aspx

This how ever makes it unable to get keyboard input, so maybe put another method on a TextBox like:

txtBoxTestFocus_MouseDown or txtBoxTestFocus_TouchDown which then could set txtBoxTestFocus.Focusable = true;

Not sure is this will help, as I've been unable to test it sorry

Comment: It seems this is the only way to do so, if you don't want to sacrifice possibility to automate UI. You can handle possibility to type into not focusable text box by registering class handler for some mouse event (e.g. `PreviewMouseDownEvent`), and focus clicked object programmatically.